# TightVnc server shows only a grey screen

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, tightvnc, vncviewer

I am trying to reach a TightVnc server on an Ubuntu machine with VNC Viewer from a Windows machine. TightVnc was already installed, so I started it with: *vncserver :1*

If I am connecting to it from a VNC Viewer, i see only a grey background (no gnome desktop):

[image]

My xstartup file (generated automatically by vncserver):

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

Someone suggested to change this to (to start gnome explicitly):

```
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
```

The result:

[image]

Nautilus is started, but no desktop is shown. What am I missing? How can I reach the gnome desktop as well?

Thank you for any good suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

After installation of gnome-session-flashback ( sudo apt install gnome-session-flashback ),
"Applications" and "Places" are appear...